# Jquery regex patterns not validating

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm working on a web page using Java servlets and JSPs. I'm currently having trouble with my login page using HTML forms and using Jquery for some quick client-side validation using regex patterns. I'm running and compiling on the latest version of Intellij ultimate.

When writing the validation using regex patterns and testing it the first time it worked perfectly fine and displayed the message only when it broke the regex pattern. Now, however, after starting my laptop back up it's saying my pattern is being broken even when I'm giving a valid input. I've tested my regex online and all my patterns are doing what I want them to.

For some reason it allows me to enter one character into the input field and it accepted it but any more than one character and it displays my message saying the pattern has been broken.

Is this a problem with the way I'm writing it or is it a bug with Jquery?

edit: after starting my laptop up again I'm now getting no validation at all, its as if its not detecting my javascript file.

I have my javascript written in a different file and have linked as so in the head along with the links to use Jquery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script src="form_validation.js"></script>
```

My form:

```
<form action="CreateAccount" method="post" name = "CreateAccountForm" id = "CreateAccountForm">
    <label for="firstname">First name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"><br>

    <label for="lastname">Last name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname"><br>

    <label for="username">Username:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br>

    <label for="password">Password</label><br>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br>

    <label for="phone">Phone Number</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone"><br>

    <label for="email">Email</label><br>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email"><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

My Jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $('CreateAccountForm').validate({
        rules: {
            firstname:{
                required:true,
                pattern: /^[a-zA-Z]+$/,
                maxlength: 50

            },
            lastname:{
                required:true,
                pattern: /^[a-zA-Z]+$/,
                maxlength: 50
            },
            username:{
                required:true,
                pattern: /^[^ ]+$/,
                maxlength: 50
            },
            password:{
                required:true,
                pattern: /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,15}$/
            },
            phone:{
                required:true,
                pattern: /^\d{2}-\d{4}-\d{7}$/
            },
            email:{
                required:true,
                email:true,
                maxlength: 50
            }

        },
        messages:{
            firstname:{
                required: " A first name is required",
                pattern: " First name must only contain characters a-z",
                maxlength: "Must be less than 50 characters"


            },
            lastname:{
                required: " A last name is required",
                pattern: " Last name must only contain characters a-z",
                maxlength: "Must be less than 50 characters"
            },
            username:{
                required: " A user name is required",
                pattern: " User name cannot have spaces",
                maxlength: "Must be less than 50 characters"
            },
            password:{
                required: " A password is required",
                pattern: " Password must contain: " +
                    "At least one upper case letter, " +
                    "At least one lower case letter, " +
                    "At least one number " +
                    "and be between 8-15 characters."
            },
            phone:{
                required: " A phone number is required",
                pattern: " Phone number must be in the format **-****-*******"
            },
            email:{

                required: " An email is required",
                email: " Not a valid email address format",
                maxlength: "Must be less than 50 characters"
            }

        }

    })

})
```

Comment: Check for errors in the console - your code provided has a major error (no # in the id selector) but then also gives an error when validating

Comment: Which jQuery plugin are you using? Are you using something different from https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/ ?

Comment: @Technoh the library is included in the question

Comment: Thanks, that means you at least one thing wrong. I'll write an answer.

Comment: There's no `max_length` method, the method is `maxlength` - it tells you this in the console errors ("check max_length method") - voting close as a typo.

Comment: You've been asked about three times now... **do you have any errors in your JavaScript console?**

Comment: You have another typo.  Your jQuery selector is missing the `#` symbol for `id`.  Should be `$('#CreateAccountForm').validate({...})`  Otherwise, it's working:  https://jsfiddle.net/y2r9kq3u/

Comment: No I have no errors in my chrome console and even after changing to `$('#CreateAccountForm').validate({...})`  I'm still not getting any validation at all so I'm assuming the error is to do with my IDE or something because as shown by Sparky when its put into jsfiddle it works perfectly fine

Comment: After removing `<script src="form_validation.js"></script>` compiling it then adding it back in and recompiling it seems to be working for now. However, I've done that before and only seemed to fix it until I restarted my computer, after which it broke again

Comment: As posted in the question, after fixing the selector, your code is working:  https://jsfiddle.net/y2r9kq3u/  - Otherwise, I have no idea how restarting your computer would have to do with anything.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) there is no `max_length` validation, the correct one to use is `maxlength`. So something like this:

```
        firstname:{
            required:true,
            pattern: /^[a-zA-Z]+$/,
            maxlength: 50
        }, // etc.
```

Comment: yeah I realised that and I've changed it maxlength, the error still persists.

Comment: Is the error after adding more than one correct character triggered on all elements or only on some?

Comment: its was happening on all elements but now no validation is taking place what so ever, its as if its now ignoring the whole form_validation.js file

Comment: nope no errors in the console in chrome or in the IDE